# Question regarding Collection hide

Tags: 3d-view

I want to ask the community how to hide collection or grouped objects.

My attempt in creating this function was to close the eye icon on the layer panel. I didnt have any luck with this method. The eye is closed for the collection and group.. yet the objects are still visible in the viewport.

The only thing that seems to work is closing the eye for each individual object.
Im wonder if the community might know of a better way as this method takes a lot of time.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the complete Blender window via the Window > Save Screenshot menu. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Talking about collections, why don't you simply untick the checkbox _Exclude from View Layer_?